# Haskell's mapM equivalent for Scala cats

Tags: scala, scala-cats

Does cats provide a function equivalent to mapM in Haskell?
It should look like:

```
  def mapM[A, B, F[_], Col[_]]
  (col: Col[A])(f: A => F[B])(implicit F: Applicative[F], T: Traverse[Col]): F[Col[B]] = 
    T.sequence[F, B](F.map(col)(f))
```

Unfortunately I haven't found any function like this one =(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called `traverse`:

```
scala> import cats.implicits._
import cats.implicits._

scala> List(1, 2, 3).traverse(n => Option((n * 2).toString))
res1: Option[List[String]] = Some(List(2, 4, 6))
```